# AngularJS Empty Result in Second URL

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Expected Result:** Opens up `Title` and `Comment` in `titleDetails.html` when `Title` is clicked in `index.html`.

**Problem:** URL changes to `http://localhost:3000/titleDetails.html` when `Title` is clicked.

But content remains the same. Page displays 0 post when I refreshed the URL.

**Screenshot:** *(index.html) & (titleDetails.html after clicking a title in index.html)*
[image]

**Screenshot:** *(after refreshing titleDetails.html when content remains the same after redirecting from index.html)*

[image]

**Code:**

**1) index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="BlogApp">
<head>
<base href="/" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="BlogController">
        <h1>Blog</h1>
            <input ng-model="post.title" class="form-control" placeholder="title"/>
            <textarea ng-model="post.body" class="form-control" placeholder="body"></textarea>
            <button ng-click="createPost(post)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Post</button>
            <button ng-click="updatePost(post)" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Update</button>

            <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
                <h2>
                    <a ng-click="titleDetails(post)">{{ post.title }} </a>
                    <a ng-click="editPost(post._id)" class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                    <a ng-click="deletePost(post._id)" class="pull-right"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                </h2>
                <em>{{post.posted}}</em>
                <p>{{post.body}}</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**2) titleDetails.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="BlogApp">
<head>
<base href="/" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="container" ng-controller="BlogController">
        <h1>Blog</h1>
            <div>
                <h2>
                    <a>{{ postDetail.title }} </a>
                </h2>
                    <em>{{postDetail.posted}}</em>
                    <p>{{postDetail.body}}</p>
            </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**3) app.js**

```
(function () {
    angular
    .module("BlogApp", [])
    .config(function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    })
    .controller("BlogController", BlogController);

    function BlogController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location) {
        $scope.createPost = createPost;
        $scope.deletePost = deletePost;
        $scope.editPost = editPost;
        $scope.updatePost = updatePost;
        $scope.titleDetails = titleDetails;
        $scope.postDetail = null;

    function init() {
        getAllPosts();
    }
    init();

    function titleDetails(post)
    { 
        $scope.postDetail = post; 
        $location.path('/titleDetails.html'); 
    }

    function updatePost(post){
        console.log(post);
        $http
        .put("/api/blogpost/"+post._id, post)
        .success(getAllPosts);
    }

    function editPost(postId){
        $http
        .get("/api/blogpost/"+postId)
        .success(function(post){
            $scope.post = post;
        });
    }

        function deletePost(postId){
            $http
            .delete("/api/blogpost/"+postId)
            .success(getAllPosts);
        }

        function getAllPosts(){
            $http
            .get("/api/blogpost")
            .success(function(posts) {
                $scope.posts = posts;
            });
        }

        function createPost(post) {
            console.log(post);
            $http
            .post("/api/blogpost",post)
            .success(getAllPosts);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Angualar is used for single page application development. Go through [SPA with angular](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS is a SPA (single page application) oriented. Your links are still tied to the classic multiple page navigation. You will have to re-work your app since `$location` and `$http.get` are not the correct services for loading templates and navigation in your scenario.

AngularJS can load the template and update the address bar accordingly as long you use the `$routeProvider`. [Scoth.io made a simple tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) on how to setup routing.

But you basically have to include `ngRoute` to your application:

```
angular.module('ngRouteExample', ['ngRoute'])
```

Then configure your routes:

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'blogPosts.html',
      controller: 'BlogController'
    })
    .when('/post/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'titleDetails.html',
      controller: 'TitleController'
    });
}
```

Since the answer can get very long, the following Plunker demonstrates a simple routing implementation for you to learn:

https://plnkr.co/edit/twmbG0G9XjOqF82JtyMC?p=preview